# Remove first and last specific symbol

Tags: python

How I can remove first and last " i " from input text? 1st variant removes text last letter and duplicates:

```
Entered TexEntered Text
          ^           ^
```

2nd variant does nothing.

Code:

```
txt4 = input("Enter text: ")
txt4 = txt4.swapcase()
print(txt4)
x = "I" or "i"
x1 = txt4.find(x)
x2 = txt4.rfind(x)
if [x1, x2] == -1:
    print("Letter \"i\" not found!")
else:
    #txt4 = txt4.replace(txt4[0:(x1+1)], "", 1) #]
    #txt4 = txt4.replace(txt4[(x2):0], "", 1)   #]-2nd variant
    #txt4x1 = txt4[:(x1+1)] + txt4[(x2):]       #]
    txt4x1 = txt4[0:x1]+txt4[(x1+1):]
    txt4x1 = txt4[0:x2]+txt4[(x2+1):]
    print(txt4x1)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: also, `x = "I" or "i"` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @zwol so how to fix it?

Comment: `[x1, x2] == -1` likewise doesn't work - this code has quite a few cases of wishful thinking as to what the language constructs do - I'd suggest reading some more on how these things work. What you want there is `x1 == -1 and x2 == -1` or `all(value == -1 for value in [x1, x2])`. It's also unclear for me what you want to do - do you only want to remove the `"i"`s if they appear at both ends of the text?

Comment: If I just show you the correct code, you won't learn anything.

Comment: @zwol S.O. is not a classroom - I can understand not wanting to answer if you feel the question is low-effort, but being condescending isn't helpful either.

Comment: @Latty SO is indeed not a classroom, *and that's why I don't want to answer the question*. I'm not being condescending, I'm attempting to redirect the OP toward a learning resource that they will actually benefit from.

Comment: @Latty I'll show you an example what I want. Input: `This day is beautiful` Output: `tHS DAY IS BEAUTFUL` (by not effecting "i" in middle)

Comment: @zwol OK, but I feel there is some low-hanging fruit for explanation here, without it needing to be a full education session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('i', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
txt = input("Enter text: ")
# re.sub() always searches from left, so we reverse txt using slice [::-1]
# to find the last match. Then we flip it again.
txt = regex.sub('', txt[::-1], 1)
txt = regex.sub('', txt[::-1], 1)
print(txt)
```

Another, shorter way of doing the same.

```
txt = input("Enter text: ")
for direction in 'from right', 'from left':  # do it twice
     txt = re.sub('[iI]', '', txt[::-1], count=1)
print(txt)
```

Comment: This is the better solution. Hopefully my post shows where the original code was going wrong and how to do the things being attempted, but for the overall problem, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are trying to do use `or` and `==` against a list in ways they simply don't work in Python.

You need to make the check over each character individually.

```
swappedCase = input("Enter text: ").swapcase()
print(swappedCase)
letters = {"I", "i"}
leftPositions = {swappedCase.find(letter) for letter in letters}
leftPos = min((position for position in leftPositions if position > -1), default=-1)
rightPos = max(swappedCase.rfind(letter) for letter in letters)
if leftPos > -1 or rightPos > -1:
    altered = swappedCase
    if leftPos > -1:
        altered = altered[:leftPos]+txt4[leftPos+1:]
    if rightPos > -1:
        altered = altered[:rightPos]+txt4[rightPos+1:]
    print(altered)
else:
    print("Letter \"i\" not found!")
```

Instead of `"I" or "i"` (which just always returns `"I"`, because it's the first `True` value), we do a `find()` and `rfind()` for each one (from a set), and then find the minimum value that's not `-1` and the maximum value to find the leftmost and rightmost occurrences, then we can do the replacements, roughly as you did before.